# Reversing Excel's Text Import Wizard for CSV Export

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export, import

I have a CSV file that I want to import to excel, edit, and save back as CSV.

The problem that I encounter is with Text Import Wizard: I open a new Excel file, then Data > From Text, and in The text Import Wizard I pick delimited>comma>Finish. This shows the data in easy-to-read columns. I make the needed changes, then I want to export as CSV, but if I go through File > Save As > CSV, it's no longer in the original format, it does not have commas/quotation marks because the Import Wizard removed them.

Is it possible to go in reverse with the import wizard and add back the commas? How can one import CSV, make changes, and export to CSV keeping the formatting exactly as it was?

I am using Excel 2007, Windows 7 PC.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the incoming format is "escaping" the commas with double quotes as the default import method assumes?  If not you have to change the `Text Qualifier` to `{none}` or whatever it is using (perhaps single quotes?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the 'Text Qualifier' to 'None' did the trick for keeping the double quotes; but when I Save as CSV, the new file has the data separated to several columns, it does not join columns with commas, as it was in the original. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which CSV are you using?  My Excel 2010 has 3 of them. 1- CSV (Comma Delimited)  2- CSV (Macintosh) 3-CSV (MS-DOS).  Also check your Region and Language settings in the windows control panel (see (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/))

Comment: In Save As, I use "CSV (Comma Delimited).csv." I see the other two as well: CSV (Macintosh), CSV (MS-DOS).

Comment: looks like you responded before my edit.  Check your regional settings too.

Comment: Checked and the List Separator was was set to semicolon (;), I changed it to comma (,) but unfortunately no luck, same issue.
FYI, when I save as CSV, I hit "yes" to the prompt, "...may contain features that are not compatible with CSV...". Not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: I think, at this point, posting a couple sample rows (anonymized as necessary) would help.  It's hard to know why excel is doing what it's doing for output, unless the input is known.  May want to check for special whitespace (CR/LF, LF, etc).  A program like Notepad++ can show you what's really in the input file.

Comment: Issue is resolved, the Regional Settings fixed the problem.

When I had the Separator set to (;) in there, the CSV file showed as below:


[A1]Last Name,"Middle Name","First Name","Employee Code"
[A2]SMITH,"","John","1"
...
But now, when I open the original CSV file, it shows everything in separate cells:

[A1]Last Name [B1]Middle Name [C1]First Name [D1]Employee Code
[A2]SMITH [B2](blank) [C2]John [D2] 1

So I can make the changes needed, then Save As CSV and the changes and formatting is preserved.

Comment: ... The Import Wizard is no longer needed, I just double-click to open the file with excel. Thanks for your help, Madball73.

Comment: I've resummarized this as an answer.  Please "accept" the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Solution involves understanding the both incoming format (i.e. what is being used as an escape character and separator) and setting the export behavior of excel.

1. Change the `Text Qualifier` to `{none}` in the import data wizard
2. Despite its name, Excel can export to CSV using other delimiters, and uses settings from the windows regional settings to decide (as detailed [here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/)).  Make sure that you have the `list delimiter` set to comma in this case.